# How do I compare a date from one table with the date present in another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to generate a report every day for exception which have occurred today.

I have a column "Exception Details" where I store the details of the exception along with the date on which it occurred.

I have another table where i store my current date which changes everyday.

I need to compare these two dates and if they match then i am generating a `CSV report`.

I have managed to generate the reports by manually by adding the dates in my query but I would be automating it so i need a query which would automatically pick up the current date from my table and compare it with date present in the "Excepton Details".

So far i have managed to write below query:

```
SELECT * FROM EXCEPTION
WHERE EXP_STAT  = 'OPEN'
AND SUBSTR(EXCEPTION_DETAILS ,INSTR(EXCEPTION_DETAILS,'2014-01-22')) = '2014-01-22'
```

I need to change this so that I can just Pick up whatever date is present in "Exception Details" and compare it with the date in another table and get the records based on that.

Comment: Can you please describe your tables using `desc` command.

Comment: Assume: Table A (EXP_STAT varchar2(5), Exception_details Varchar2(500)) Table B( current_date Date )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to it using ReGEX:

SELECT * FROM EXCEPTION WHERE EXP_STAT = 'OPEN' AND REGEXP_SUBSTR(EXCEPTION_DETAILS, 
                '(19|20)\d\d- -.- -.') = (select to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from calendar_table where date_type='CURRENT')

Comment: Edit the answer to see the entire query. Seems to have been cut short while displaying the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tableA.* FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.EXP_STAT  = 'OPEN'
AND SUBSTR(EXCEPTION_DETAILS ,INSTR(EXCEPTION_DETAILS,to_char(tableB.current_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')),12) = to_char(tableB.current_date,'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Assuming your date table , don't have repetitive dates.

Comment: SUBSTR(EXCEPTION_DETAILS ,INSTR(EXCEPTION_DETAILS,to_char(tableB.current_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')),12)... this is not related to tableB.current_date. It could be any date. i just need to fetch and compare it with the date in tableB

Answer (score 0):

I have change your query please try it out it must help you

```
SELECT * FROM EXCEPTION WHERE EXP_STAT = 'OPEN' AND SUBSTR(EXCEPTION_DETAILS ,INSTR(EXCEPTION_DETAILS,select to_char(max(dt_date),'yyyy-mm-dd') from table2)) = (select to_char(max(dt_date),'yyyy-mm-dd') from table2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering, why are you actually storing current date on another table? why are you not simply comparing with TRUNC(SYSDATE)?

Anyways,

```
SELECT * FROM EXCEPTION, B
WHERE EXP_STAT  = 'OPEN'
AND TO_DATE(SUBSTR(EXCEPTION_DETAILS ,INSTR(EXCEPTION_DETAILS,'2014-01-22')),'DD-MM-YY') = TRUNC(B.CURRENT_DATE);
```

Comment: Check for any syntactical errors though, havn't tried it on a actual environment, don't have one right now

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to involve so many functions, one instr is enough:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM EXCEPTION
    WHERE EXP_STAT  = 'OPEN'
      AND INSTR(EXCEPTION_DETAILS,'2014-01-22') > 0;
```

To fetch using another table, assuming that you want to compare with the date_field column of some_date_table table

```
SELECT e.*
  FROM EXCEPTION e
 inner join some_date_table s
 WHERE e.EXP_STAT  = 'OPEN'
   AND INSTR(e.EXCEPTION_DETAILS,to_char(s.date_field, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) > 0;
```